# Multiprocessing vs. Code Enhancement in my Python Code

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, openpyxl

**Background:** I have a script that reads 200+ Outlines (groups) of data from a `.xlsx` file and writes them to individual worksheets in a separately created `.xlsx` and names them appropriately, whilst appropriately preserving the Outlines.

**Script:** the following script achieves this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def get_client_rows(sheet):
    """Get client rows.

    Skip header and then look for row dimensions without outline level
    """
    return [row[0].row for row in sheet.iter_rows(2) if row[0].alignment.indent == 0.0]
    return [
        row_index
        for row_index, row_dimension in sheet.row_dimensions.items()
        if row_index > 1 and row_dimension.outline_level == 0
    ]


def delete_client_block(sheet, start, end):
    """
    Delete rows starting from up to and including end.
    """
    for row in range(start, end + 1):
        sheet.row_dimensions.pop(row, None)
    sheet.delete_rows(start, end - start + 1)


def split_workbook(input_file, output_file):
    """
    Split workbook each main group into its own sheet.

    Not to lose any formatting we copy the current sheet and remove all rows
    which do not belong to extacted group.
    """

    try:
        workbook = load_workbook(input_file)
        data_sheet = workbook.active
        client_rows = get_client_rows(data_sheet)

        for index, client_row in enumerate(client_rows):
            # create new sheet for given client, shorten client as it might be too long
            client_sheet = workbook.copy_worksheet(data_sheet)
            client_sheet.title = data_sheet.cell(client_row, 1).value[:32]
            print("Creating New Client Workbook")

            # delete rows after current client if available
            if index < len(client_rows) - 1:
                row_after_client = client_rows[index + 1]
                delete_client_block(
                    client_sheet, row_after_client, client_sheet.max_row
                )

            # delete rows before current client if available
            if index > 0:
                first_client_row = client_rows[0]
                delete_client_block(
                    client_sheet, first_client_row, client_row - first_client_row + 1
                )

                # move left over dimensions to top of the sheet
                for row_index in list(client_sheet.row_dimensions.keys()):
                    # skip header row dimension
                    if row_index > first_client_row - 1:
                        row_dimension = client_sheet.row_dimensions.pop(row_index)
                        new_index = row_index - client_row + first_client_row
                        row_dimension.index = new_index
                        client_sheet.row_dimensions[new_index] = row_dimension

        del workbook[data_sheet.title]
        workbook.save(output_file)
    finally:
        workbook.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = 'input.xlsx'
    output_file = "output.xlsx"
    split_workbook(input_file, output_file)
```

**My issue:** the script works fine when working with a smaller file (e.g. < 5MB / 10k rows) however having tried on a larger file (e.g., 50MB file / >100k rows) I get the following `MemoryError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scripts/BillingPull/main.py", line 80, in <module>
    split_workbook(input_file, output_file)
  File "C:/scripts/BillingPull/main.py", line 41, in split_workbook
    client_sheet = workbook.copy_worksheet(data_sheet)
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 434, in copy_worksheet
    cp.copy_worksheet()
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\copier.py", line 37, in copy_worksheet
    self._copy_dimensions()
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\copier.py", line 69, in _copy_dimensions
    target[key] = copy(dim)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\copy.py", line 84, in copy
    return copier(x)
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\dimensions.py", line 60, in __copy__
    cp.__init__(**attrib)
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\dimensions.py", line 107, in __init__
    super(RowDimension, self).__init__(index, hidden, outlineLevel,
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\dimensions.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.outlineLevel = outlineLevel
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 68, in __set__
    super(Convertible, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 43, in __set__
    super(Typed, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\scripts\BillingPull\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 24, in __set__
    instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
MemoryError
```

**My question:** I am running this script on a x64-based PC virtual server that has the following specs -

- Processor    AMD EPYC 7763 64-Core Processor, 2445 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
- Physical RAM: 16.0 GB
- Virtual Memory: 31.8 GB
- Windows v. 10

Should I be exploring using Multithreading to optimize runtime of my script, or is this a case of code optimization?

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-memoryerror/#:~:text=MemoryError%20in%20Python.-,the%20MemoryError%20in%20Python,solution%20for%20such%20a%20situation. This would be a cod optimization problem for the larger files, multithreading would still have the same issues most likely just in a faster time. The code optimization would have to be focused on memory and not just speed.

Comment: your memory error is coming from `client_sheet = workbook.copy_worksheet(data_sheet)` because your larger files are too much memory to copy over. you may want to consider splitting the amount copied, saving (and free up that memory), and continuing to copy over larger files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AndrewRyan - I'll post an answer, once I've optimized, so you can see how I handled.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense: if memory is an issue then multiprocessing will only make things worse. It's not clear from your code if you're editing workbooks but if not then try combining read-only and write-only modes. But, basically you should add more memory to your system.

Comment: @CharlieClark kudos on the advice. I used exactly those modules. Specifically, I utilized the `output_workbook = Workbook(write_only=True)`. Full script below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I was able to revisit how the code functioned and find optimizations. Specifically, `openpyxl` contains `openpyxl.worksheet._read_only.ReadOnlyWorksheet`. Documentation [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html) -

> Sometimes, you will need to open or write extremely large XLSX files,
> and the common routines in openpyxl won’t be able to handle that load.
> Fortunately, there are two modes that enable you to read and write
> unlimited amounts of data with (near) constant memory consumption.

**Revised code:**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import LXML
import time
from copy import copy
from openpyxl.cell import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl import Workbook

import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger()


def configure_logging():
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


INVALID_TITLE_CHARS = ["]", "[", "*", ":", "?", "/", "\\", "'"]
INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP = {ord(x): "" for x in INVALID_TITLE_CHARS}


def clean_sheet_title(title):
    title = title or ""
    title = title.strip()
    title = title.translate(INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP)
    return title[:31]


def is_client_row(row, row_dimension):
    return row[0].alignment.indent == 0.0
    # return row_dimension.outline_level == 0


def create_write_only_cell(source_cell, target_sheet):
    target_cell = WriteOnlyCell(target_sheet, value=source_cell.value)
    target_cell.data_type = source_cell.data_type

    if source_cell.has_style:
        target_cell.font = copy(source_cell.font)
        # TODO save one border and use it
        # target_cell.border = copy(source_cell.border)
        # TODO copy client row
        # target_cell.fill = copy(source_cell.fill)
        target_cell.number_format = copy(source_cell.number_format)
        # target_cell.protection = copy(source_cell.protection)
        target_cell.alignment = copy(source_cell.alignment)

    return target_cell


def create_write_only_row(source_row, target_sheet):
    return [create_write_only_cell(cell, target_sheet) for cell in source_row]


def split_workbook(input_file, output_file):
    """
    Split workbook each client into its own sheet.
    """
    try:
        logger.info(f"Loading workbook {input_file}")
        workbook = load_workbook(input_file)
        data_sheet = workbook.active
        output_workbook = Workbook(write_only=True)
        client_sheet = None
        client_row_index = 2
        processing_client = 0

        rows = data_sheet.rows
        header = next(rows)
        for index, row in enumerate(rows, start=2):
            # TODO implement skip row
            # if skip_row(row) is True:
            #     continue
            row_dimension = data_sheet.row_dimensions[index]

            # create new sheet found new client is found
            if is_client_row(row, row_dimension):
                processing_client += 1
                client_sheet_title = clean_sheet_title(row[0].value)
                logger.info(f"Processing client {processing_client}")
                client_sheet = output_workbook.create_sheet(client_sheet_title)
                client_row_index = index

                # copy column dimensions
                for key, column_dimension in data_sheet.column_dimensions.items():
                    client_sheet.column_dimensions[key] = copy(column_dimension)
                    client_sheet.column_dimensions[key].worksheet = client_sheet

                client_sheet.append(create_write_only_row(header, client_sheet))

            # copy row dimensions
            client_sheet.row_dimensions[index - client_row_index + 2] = copy(
                row_dimension
            )
            client_sheet.row_dimensions[index].worksheet = client_sheet

            # finally copy row
            client_sheet.append(create_write_only_row(row, client_sheet))

            if index % 10000 == 0:
                logger.info(f"{index} rows processed")

        logger.info(f"Writing workbook {output_file}")
        output_workbook.save(output_file)
    finally:
        if workbook:
            workbook.close()
        if output_workbook:
            output_workbook.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = "input_file.xlsx"
    output_file = "output_file.xlsx"

    start = time.time()
    configure_logging()

    logger.info(f"Using lxml mode: {LXML}")
    split_workbook(input_file, output_file)
    logger.info("Time consumed: % s seconds" % (time.time() - start))
```